# Is Alphabet check in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I check whether a character is a valid Alphabet in sql-server ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to check a column doesn't contain any strange characters or numbers?

Comment: Also, do your databases/tables/columns have a case sensitive collation?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what **you** define as alphabet character. You can check the ascii code and decide for yourself if it is valid or not by setting the valid range:

```
select ASCII('Z') between 97 and 122 and ASCII('Z') between 65 and 90
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create function isAlpha( @aChar varchar)
returns int
as
begin
    declare @anAsc int
    set @anAsc = ascii(@aChar)
    -- 65 = A
    -- 90 = Z
    return
        case 
            when @anAsc < 65 then 0
            when @anAsc > 90 then 0
            else 1
        end
end
```